# Javascript Function.prototype.call()

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I read some article and it said the following 2 line are doing the same thing.

```
fn.call(thisValue);
Function.prototype.call.call(fn, thisValue);
```

For line 1, my understanding is that every function object in Javascript do have a the method `call` inherited from the `Function.prototype` and what `call` method does is to have the `this` keyword inside the function definition of `fn` to be `thisValue`(the first parameter I passed in the call method. `fn` is a function so what I am doing in `fn.call(thisValue)` is just invoking `fn` and set the `this` keyword inside the function to be `thisValue`.

But For line 2, I don't get it. Can someone help to explain it what the hack the line 2 is doing.

Comment: Are you sure there should be two `call` in `Function.prototype.call.call(fn, thisValue);`

Comment: Function.prototype.call.call === Function.prototype.bind, this is the same behavior

Comment: regarding jQuery, `fn`is just alias for `prototype` property.

Comment: @Pinal: can you explain a bit more why they are the same?

Comment: @DavorMlinaric: This is absolutely irrelevant for this question.

Comment: @Pinal: not really, `call !== bind`.

Comment: @Tushar: yes, it doesn't work without.

Comment: @bufferoverflow76: would you mind linking the article where you've read that? Just so that we can answer in context.

Comment: In the extra, extra credit section [link](http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with this setup:

```
function fn() { console.log(this); }
var thisvalue = {fn: fn};
```

Now you surely understand that `thisvalue.fn()` is a method call, and sets the logged `this` value to the `thisvalue` object.

Next, you seem to know that `fn.call(thisvalue)` does exactly the same call. Alternatively, we could write `(thisvalue.fn).call(thisvalue)` (parentheses just for structure, could be omitted) as `thisvalue.fn === fn`:

```
thisvalue.fn(…); // is equivalent to
(thisvalue.fn).call(thisvalue, …); // or:
(fn).call(thisvalue, …);
```

OK, but `fn.call(…)` is just a method call as well - the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) of functions is called on the `fn` function.
It can be accessed as such because all function objects inherit this `.call` property from `Function.prototype` - it's not an own property like `.fn` on the `thisvalue` object. However, `fn.call === Function.prototype.call` is the same as `thisvalue.fn === fn`.

Now, we can rewrite that method call of `.call` as an explicit invocation with `.call()`:

```
fn.call(thisvalue); // is equivalent to
(fn.call).call(fn, thisvalue); // or:
(Function.protoype.call).call(fn, thisvalue);
```

I hope you spot the pattern and can now explain why the following work as well:

```
Function.prototype.call.call.call(Function.prototype.call, fn, thisvalue);
var call = Function.prototype.call; call.call(call, fn, thisvalue);
```

Breaking this down is left as an exercise to the reader :-)

Comment: `Function.prototype.call.call.call(Function.prototype.call, fn, thisvalue);` --> `(Function.prototype.call.call).call(Function.prototype.call, fn, thisvalue);` --> `Function.prototype.call.call(fn, thisvalue);` --> `(fn.call).call(fn, thisvalue) --> fn.call(thisvalue);`
so, in general, the formula to simply is that:
`(x.method).call(x, params...)` -->  `x.method(params...)`

Answer (score 1):

Since I ended up here trying to understand [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490211/cant-use-function-prototype-call-directly/44490793#44490793), I'm gonna post my answer here as well.

Let's start with this:

```
function fn() { console.log(this); }
fn.a = function(){console.log(this)} // "this" is fn because of the . when calling
fn.a() // function fn() { console.log(this); }
```

So let's dig deeper and try to reimplement the `call` function:

```
  Function.prototype.fakeCall = function () {
    // taking the arguments after the first one
    let arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    try{
       return this.apply(arguments[0], arr);
    }catch(e){}
  }

  function a(ar){ console.log(ar + this.name) };
  let obj = {name : "thierry"};
  // a.fakeCall( obj, 'hi ')

  Function.fakeCall.fakeCall(a, obj, 'hi ');
```

Thus when we do this: `Function.prototype.fakeCall.fakeCall(a, obj, 'hi ')`

what happens is, on the first run we have:

> 1. `arr = [ obj, 'hi ']`
> 2. `this = Function.fakeCall`

so we end up with `Function.fakeCall.apply(a, [ obj, 'hi ']);`

Then on the second run we have

> 1. `arr = ['hi']`
> 2. `this = a`

so we end up with  `a.apply(obj, ['hi'])` which is the same as `a.call(obj, 'hi');`

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44490793/4299560)

Comment: This question has more than one facet. 
 Your answer pertains to this one: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710853/how-does-function-prototype-call-work-under-the-hood

Comment: @ChavaG I really don't see how the answer above me answers anything that wasn't already known to OP. He just said that `fn.call === Function.prototype.call` which OP knew already.