# Why can't I .call() Function.call?

Tags: javascript, call

In Javascript, `Function.call()` can call `Function` given a `this` value and zero or more arguments.

`Function.call` itself is a function. So in theory, `Function.call` should be the same (or similarly acting) function as `Function.call.call`.

In V8, this seems to be the case:

```
> Function.call === Function.call.call
true
```

When we call `Function.call()`, we get an anonymous function

```
> Function.call()
[Function: anonymous]
```

However, I can't call `.call()` on `Function.call`.

```
> Function.call.call()
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at repl:1:21
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
at bound (domain.js:291:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:304:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
```

---

What is going on here? `Function.call` is clearly a function - it's not `undefined` as this error message suggests.

Comment: Nice question and answer, even though pointless in a normal programming context :)

Comment: @nicovank Of course, but I was exploring some "what if's" of Javascript and encountered this accidentally. :)

Comment: [Of course you can](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31074664/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi If you pass in a `this` value, sure. The confusion stemmed from the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** The error message is *very* misleading. It is the same error message you get when you do

```
(undefined)();
```

---

**Longer answer:**

The second `.call()` is being invoked with a `this` of `Function.call`.

Calling it with no parameters causes it to call `this` with `undefined` as the `this` value.

Therefore, you're really doing

```
Function.call.call(undefined)
```

which means you're (metaphorically) doing

```
undefined.call()
```

which is really just

```
undefined()
```

Passing nothing (or `undefined`) to the `this` parameter of `Function.call.call()` is essentially negating the `this` context of the first `Function.call()` (which would be just `Function` itself), causing `.call()` to be invoked on `undefined`.

This yields the error message that is produced: `undefined is not a function`.

Comment: …so working examples would be `Function.call.call(Function)` or `Function.call.call(console.log, console, "hello")`

Comment: @Bergi Correct. Again, the confusion stemmed from the _error message_.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you self-answered your question. I just thought that adding an example of working double-`call` usage might benefit the explanation.