# Why is function.call.call not a function?

Tags: javascript

**Code:**

```
let fun = x => x * x;
-> undefined
typeof fun.call.call
-> "function"
fun.call.call()
VM251:1 Uncaught TypeError: fun.call.call is not a function
```

Why is `fun.call.call` is not a function when `typeof fun.call.call -> "function"`?

Comment: What is purpose of chained `.call.call`?

Comment: No purpose. Just noticed something weird.

Comment: Note, no value is passed to `.call()` for `x`, you can use `fun.call(null, 2)` to get expected result

Comment: [Related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40884841/2419531). This is clearer than the one linked as duplicate.

Comment: Following comment by @Bergi at linked Question/Answer `Function.call.call(fun, null, 2)` should return expected result