# Can't use Function.prototype.call directly

Tags: javascript

```
function f(a) { return a}

f(1) // => 1

f.call(null, 1) // => 1

Function.prototype.call(f, null, 1) // => undefined
```

Why the last line return `undefined`, I thought they are the same.

Comment: `Function.prototype.call.call(f, null, 1)` What you're doing right now is `var fp = Function.prototype; fp.call(f, null, 1)` and `fp.call(...)` ain't the same as `f.call(...)`. These are simply different functions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074664/javascript-function-prototype-call

Comment: thank you guys for the quick rely, this is a mind stretcher

Comment: @mko I'd appreciate if you checked my answer, I don't think the current answer, nor the one he linked to makes a good job of answering the question. That's just my opinion though.

Comment: @mko I updated my answer to give you a digestible explanation of the difference between `Function.prototype.call` and `Function.prototype.call.call` based on the specification of how Function.prototype.call is really supposed to work.  Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These will be the same:

```js
function f(a) { return a}

console.log(f(1)); // => 1

console.log(f.call(null, 1)); // => 1

console.log(Function.prototype.call.call(f, null, 1)); // => 1
```

Notice the additional `.call` in the last statement.

And here's the explanation:

### Function.prototype.call

According to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.call), `Function.prototype.call` returns an abstract operation *Call(func, thisArg, argList)*.

Therefore, `f.call(null, 1)` will return the abstract operation *Call(f, null, 1)* where *f* is the function being called, *null* is the context from which it is called, and *1* is the argument passed to *f*.  This will give you the desired output.

Based on that, `Function.prototype.call(f, null, 1)` will result in the abstract operation *Call(Function.prototype, f, null, 1)* where *Function.prototype* is the function being called, *f* is the context, and *null* and *1* are the arguments passed to *Function.prototype*.  Of course this will not work as intended.

### Function.prototype.call.call

However, `Function.prototype.call.call(f, null, 1)` will return the abstract call operation *Call(Function.prototype.call, f, null, 1)*, where *Function.prototype.call* is the function to be called, ***f* is the context from which it is called**, and *null* and *1* are passed as arguments. So what would that look like? Well, since *f* is the context and *call* is the function being invoked with *(null,1)*, the end result is identical to: `f.call(null, 1)`.

Comment: It works I need some coffee to figure this out, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with this:

```
function fn() { console.log(this); }
fn.a = function(){console.log(this)}
fn.a() // function fn() { console.log(this); }
```

So let's dig deeper and try to implement a fake `call` function:

```
  Function.prototype.fakeCall = function () {
    // console.log(this)
    // taking the arguments after the first one
    let arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    // on the first run this will be Function.fakeCall but on the second pass it will be the first argument (the a function)
    this.apply(arguments[0], arr);
  }

  function a(ar){ console.log(ar + this.name) };
  let obj = {name : "thierry"};
 // a.fakeCall( obj, 'hi ')

Function.fakeCall.fakeCall(a, obj, 'hi ');
```

Thus when we do this: `Function.prototype.fakeCall.fakeCall(a, obj, 'hi ')`

what happens is, on the first run we have:

> 1. `arr = [ obj, 'hi ']`
> 2. `this = Function.fakeCall`

so we end up with `Function.fakeCall.apply(a, [ obj, 'hi ']);`

Then on the second run we have

> 1. `arr = ['hi']`
> 2. `this = a`

so we end up with  `a.apply(obj, ['hi'])` which is the same as `a.call(obj, 'hi');`

If however we did `Function.fakeCall(a, obj, 'hi ');`
On the first run we would have `this = Function` and that won't work. It will throw an error in this case, in your case it just returns undefined. That is easily implementable with a `try-catch`.

```
  Function.prototype.fakeCall = function () {
    let arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    try{
       return this.apply(arguments[0], arr);
    }catch(e){}
  }

  function a(ar){ return ar + this.name };
  let obj = {name : "thierry"};
  console.log(Function.fakeCall(a, obj, 'hi ')); // undefined

  console.log(Function.fakeCall.fakeCall(a, obj, 'hi ')); // hi thierry
```

Comment: your style of explanation teach me more about the underlying mechanism. thank you